# Fake a cookie to scrape a site in python

Tags: python, cookies, cookiejar

The site that I'm trying to scrape uses js to create a cookie. What I was thinking was that I can create a cookie in python and then use that cookie to scrape the site. However, I don't know any way of doing that. Does anybody have any ideas?

Comment: Won't this not work in general because a site may insert a digital signature in the cookie to make sure it came from the site?

Comment: It uses javascript to create the cookie so I know how it's created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see [Python httplib2 - Handling Cookies in HTTP Form Posts](http://www.testingreflections.com/node/view/5919) for an example of adding a cookie to a request.

> I often need to automate tasks in web
>   based applications.  I like to do this
>   at the protocol level by simulating a
>   real user's interactions via HTTP. 
>   Python comes with two built-in modules
>   for this: urllib (higher level Web
>   interface) and httplib (lower level
>   HTTP interface).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do more involved browser emulation (including setting cookies) take a look at [mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/).  It's simulation capabilities are almost complete (no Javascript support unfortunately): I've used it to build several scrapers with much success.

Comment: There are a few remote control browser solutions. I like selenium, particularly since I can run it in a virtual framebuffer Xwindows. (screenshots still work just fine.) Don't know much about the others, though.

Comment: mechanize is not a browser automater, it emulates a browser at level of HTTP requests and responses.

Comment: This looks interesting, I'll take a look into it